Ejaculating in ramadan
I ejaculated in the night of ramadan what do I do? I started watching sexual content then I said a prayer to make me stop doing this sinful act,then I think 30 minutes or less later I ejaculated a small amount of semen and I can't do ghusl because there is no water, I don't know if my fast is valid the next day please respond

You can fast, it is important to be pure while fasting But if it happens then there is no problem, you can keep fasting but if you have to offer namaz then it is necessary to take ghusl.
